# How to remove stubborn kitchen faucet mount nut?

Tags: kitchens, faucet, sink, kitchen-sink

I tried to remove my faucet from old kitchen sink but the nut is tighten so hard:

[image]

I am using channel lock on the nut to turn counterclock wise and I use my hand to hold on the faucet on the other side. It's just NOT moving even after spraying WD-40.

What are the tricks to unscrew this nut?

Answer (score 1):

Since the sink is out, it should not be an issue at all. Just remove the same as any other nut... Perhaps a little more pressure? Try to squeeze the nut only tight enough to maintain a grip, too tight may be deforming the nut slightly to "pinch" the nut tighter than is seems.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an open end wrench if you have one that size or an adjustable  crescent wrench or any type wrench that does not need to be clamped onto the nut and squeezed as you do with a channel lock type pliers. The nut is made of brass and soft and can easily be distorted. One last thing, wear protective gloves since you are working around sharp metal edges.