# How could i remove this hardly accessible nut?

Tags: bathroom, toilet

I want to replace my toilet seat. But i can't really access this nut with any wrench. You can see that there's no way to get to it sideways, so my only thought was to go directly from the bottom using combination pliers. But this long screw makes it impossible to twist the nut more than 1/8th of a turn.
Could you give me some advice on this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are either of these tools suitable for tightening the pipe union nut underneath a bath?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14828/are-either-of-these-tools-suitable-for-tightening-the-pipe-union-nut-underneath)

Comment: Another: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/148020/how-to-remove-stubborn-kitchen-faucet-mount-nut

Comment: Another: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/103422/remove-fastener-nut-for-kitchen-faucet-rusted

Comment: Another: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/158266/what-tool-to-tighten-nut-on-kitchen-faucet

Answer (score 2):

A crow’s foot wrench is a suitable tool for this or a plumber’s wrench which works left or right.

See basin wrench at Home Depot...

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Pliers or a wrench turned at an odd angle is how I get them off. You only need to loosen it a little bit before you should be able to do the rest with your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

A 6" adjustable, Crescent, wrench will fit up there nicely and then turn the screw from the top.